# Oracle SQL - find and replace ASCII

Tags: sql, oracle, ascii

In my database, special characters have got inserted with these ASCII values

```
ASCII(' ')  ASCII('')   
49828          32
```

There is ASCII Value **49828** shown in the column description that is showing as special character **¤**

How do I find all the values that have this special character? and how to replace it with a regular space (ASCII 32)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you'd use `REPLACE` (as you said).

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test (col) as
  2  select 'x' || chr(67)    || 'y' from dual union all
  3  select 'x' || chr(49828) || 'y' from dual;

Table created.
```

Contents (disregard `Ą` displayed in **my** SQL*Plus & my database):

```
SQL> select * from test;

COL
----
xCy
xĄy
```

Update only rows that contain that value:

```
SQL> update test set
  2    col = replace(col, chr(49828), chr(32))
  3    where instr(col, chr(49828)) > 0;

1 row updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

COL
----
xCy
x y

SQL>
```